# Is there an else command in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a program in netlogo where there are blocks that come down the screen and when their `y-coordinate` reaches a certain value they reverse their direction and move in the opposite way.

So far I was able to make them move in one direction and then switch directions when they reach the critical `y-coordinate` value, but once they take one step in the reverse direction it glitches and they get stuck moving one step forward and one step backward.

I wanted to know if there was an `else` command in netlogo so I could specify that if the while command wasn't fulfilled it could reverse its direction and move without glitching.

Here is my code.

```
to maze 
while [abs pycor < 16 ] [fd 1 wait .1]
bk 1 wait .1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate `else` keyword in NetLogo, but the [`ifelse`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse) command allows you to specify two blocks: one that is executed if the condition is true, and another (the "else" block) that is executed if the condition is false.

It seems, however, like you should rethink your general approach to the problem. Turtles in NetLogo always face in a particular direction, and you could take advantage of that: instead of having them "back up", you could have them turn around.

Also, it's generally ill-advised to try to do things in a `while` loop. If you want your turtles to repeat a behavior, a ["forever button"](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#buttons) is usually the way to go.

In the following example, you should call the `go` procedure from a forever button:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches with [ pycor = max-pycor - 1 ] [
    sprout 1 [
      set heading 180 ; head down
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if abs pycor = max-pycor [
      rt 180 ; turn around!
    ]
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

This probably doesn't achieve exactly what you wanted, but there is a good chance that you can modify it to fit your needs.

Also note that this will work better using [tick-based updates](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#updates).